# Deconvolution and Curve Fitting

Tags: curves, deconvolution

I have a function $$g(x) = (f \star f) (x)$$, where $\star$ denotes convolution.  $g(x)$ is a piece-wise quadratic polynomial function whose exact closed-form formula I know. I want to deconvolve $g(x)$ to obtain $f(x)$. From what I understand deconvolution result is not necessarily unique (i.e. there can be many $f(x)$ that when convolved with itself may result in $g(x)$).

But I also have $f(x)$ in the form of a table (i.e. $f(x)$ vs $x$) for lots of points (and I can generate them for as many additional points as needed manually using some numeric method).  I also know that $f(x)$ probably has terms like $x^\frac{1}{2}$ (since its self-convolution results in a quadratic polynomial). The thing is I am looking for a closed-form expression for $f(x)$.

I am looking for curve-fitting that either understands convolution as a constraint or  one that can fit piecewise formula containing variables raised to non-integer powers (in my case $x^\frac{1}{2}$). Any suggestions on what tools/techniques/software I can use for my problem?

Comment: what form type of function is $f$?

Comment: Have you considered using Fourier Transform (or it discrete version, the FFT). Your convolution issue would become a square issue which is much simpler.

Comment: @JeanMarie, the numeric method and table I mentioned in my post is nothing but fourier transform that I am calculating manually as a sum. I do have the InverseFT of $f$ in a closed form, but I am not finding any closed form expressions for FT of that closed form function in order to obtain $f$. I tried Wolfram-alpha, but it fails.

Comment: @msm, I speculate $f(x)$ to be be something like $a (x-k1)^\frac{1}{2} sgn(x-k1) + b (x+k2)^\frac{1}{2} sgn(x+k2) + c ((x-k1)^\frac{1}{2} + (x+k2)^\frac{1}{2}) sgn(x)$ , but I am really not sure.

Comment: Could you describe a little the form under which you know $g$ and/or give numerical example. Is $g$ a quadratic spline function with bounded support?

Comment: Let me give you an example for $g$. Let $g(x) = (x-1)^2$ for $0 \le x < 1 $ and $(x+1)^2$ for $-1 < x < 0$ and $0$ elsewhere.